# Динамическое изменение url на jQuery

Tags: url, jquery, html

Вот примерный код. При клике на "Клик" в div с class="red" подзагружается conten_reg.php.

Как сделать, чтобы url изменялся и был рабочим?

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dlb").click(function(){
$(".red").load("conten_reg.php");
})
});
```

**Html**

```
<div class="red">
<span id="dlb">Клик</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Что-то я не совсем понял, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Обновляется div и чтоб обновлялся url и обновленный url работал, чтоб не выкидывал начальную страницу.

Comment: а алгоритм обновления url,а какой? Его conten_reg.php должен выдавать?

Answer (score 0):

Вам сюда: [jQuery hashchange event](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/).

Comment: А с помощью обычной библиотеки jquery нельзя такую вещь сделать?

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, обновление хеша - это совсем другое

Comment: блин пагано я думал что в jquery прописан скрипт работы history api